# Using scipy.stats.entropy on gmm.predict_proba() values

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, statistics

Background so I don't throw out an XY problem -- I'm trying to check the goodness of fit of a GMM because I want statistical back-up for why I'm choosing the number of clusters I've chosen to group these samples. I'm checking AIC, BIC, entropy, and root mean squared error.  This question is about entropy.

I've used kmeans to cluster a bunch of samples, and I want an entropy greater than 0.9 (stats and psychology are not my expertise and this problem is both).  I have 59 samples; each sample has 3 features in it.  I look for the best covariance type via

```
for cv_type in cv_types:
  for n_components in n_components_range:
    # Fit a Gaussian mixture with EM
    gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=n_components,
                                  covariance_type=cv_type)
    gmm.fit(data3)
```

where the n_components_range is just [2] (later I'll check 2 through 5). 
 Then I take the GMM with the lowest AIC or BIC, saved as best_eitherAB, (not shown) of the four.  I want to see if the label assignments of the predictions are stable across time (I want to run for 1000 iterations), so I know I then need to calculate the entropy, which needs class assignment probabilities.  So I predict the probabilities of the class assignment via gmm's method,

```
probabilities = best_eitherAB.predict_proba(data3)
all_probabilities.append(probabilities)
```

After all the iterations, I have an array of 1000 arrays, each contains 59 rows (sample size) by 2 columns (for the 2 classes).  Each inner row of two sums to 1 to make the probability.

Now, I'm not entirely sure what to do regarding the entropy.  I can just feed the whole thing into scipy.stats.entropy,

```
entr = scipy.stats.entropy(all_probabilities)
```

and it spits out numbers - as many samples as I have, I get a 2 item numpy matrix for each.  I could feed just one of the 1000 tests in and just get 1 small matrix of two items; or I could feed in just a single column and get a single values back. But I don't know what this is, and the numbers are between 1 and 3.

So my questions are -- am I totally misunderstanding how I can use scipy.stats.entropy to calculate the stability of my classes?  If I'm not, what's the best way to find a single number entropy that tells me how good my model selection is?